# What is the role of "master" in a tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've been working under the assumption that a widget's master is the geometric container of the widget. But recently I found that .place, .pack
and .grid all accept an option `in_` which allows you to *position* (that is, `.place`, `.pack`, or `.grid`, I'm using *position* in the sense of calling any of those methods) the widget inside a different container.

The documentation uses master, parent, and container imprecisely. I used to think they all meant the same, but clearly that's not the case.

- Something is passed - or left to default - as first argument to a
  widget's constructor. Let's call that something *master*. **The
  master is defined at construction time and cannot ever be changed**.
- A widget is shown inside its *container*. The default container is the widget's master, but it can be any widget in the master-slave chain between the widget's master and the root because, when we *(re)position* a widget, an option **`in_`** may be provided which (re)defines the widget's container. **The container is defined after 
  widget construction and can be changed by *repositioning***.

I believe these statements to be true. But if that is so, if one can put a widget elsewhere than in its master, then what does the master do (other than provide a default container)? Could one leave the master unspecified in every widget (which would make `root=Tk()` the master of every widget) and simply use **`in_`** to define their containers?

Comment: I'm not really sure why both the `master` and `in_` options exist, but they are not quite as interchangeable as you think: if you enumerate widgets (using `.winfo_children()` for example), you'll get vastly different results in the two scenarios.  Also, I think that `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events are going to follow the `master` hierarchy, not the `in_` hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think they are interchangeable and that's what puzzles me. What would be the purpose of having different in_ and master hierarchies? Shouldn't <Enter> and <Leave> follow the geometric containment (in_) hierarchy?

Comment: @Eduardo any update on this? Any revelation during the last four years?